# Amigos, como faço para visualizar apenas um usuário com esta regra

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de pegar o id do usuário e o preço relacionado a esse usuário e apenas mostrar um resultado referente a este usuário. Ex. Só quero visualizar o Mauro.

```
<?php
    // Conectando ao banco
    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "minhasenha", "meubanco");

    if (!$db_conx) { die( mysqli_connect_error() ); }
    // Consulta e constroi a lista para exibicao
    $list = "";
    $sql = "SELECT dadoscliente.nomeresponsavel, dadoscliente.email, precolevantamento.nome_preco_levantamento
            FROM dadoscliente INNER JOIN precolevantamento
            ON dadoscliente.escolha = precolevantamento.id_preco_levantamento
            WHERE precolevantamento.nome_preco_levantamento != '' ORDER BY dadoscliente.id_cliente DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die( mysqli_error($db_conx) );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $list .= 'Meu nome é <b>' .$row["nomeresponsavel"]."</b> meu email é <b>".$row["email"].'</b> e minha identificação é: <b>';
        $list .= $row["nome_preco_levantamento"].'</b></u> <hr>';
    }
    // Fechando a conexao do banco de dados
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    echo $list;
    ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer **while** quando você só quer trazer um registro, mas para facilitar sua regra, basta usar "limit" na query.

Em vez de usar um laço, traga apenas o primeiro registro:
`$row[0]['nomeresponsavel']`.

```
 $sql = "SELECT dadoscliente.nomeresponsavel, dadoscliente.email, precolevantamento.nome_preco_levantamento
            FROM dadoscliente INNER JOIN precolevantamento
            ON dadoscliente.escolha = precolevantamento.id_preco_levantamento
            WHERE precolevantamento.nome_preco_levantamento != '' ORDER BY dadoscliente.id_cliente DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```